# The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type.in eager loading

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

I try to include anonymous type like this :
I want all `incomelist` attributes in addition to `CompanyTitle` ,`PeriodTypeName` )

```
 var incomeList = ctx.IncomeLists.Include(i => new
                {
                    CompanyTitle = i.CompanyId.ToString() + "/" + i.Company.CompanyName,
                    PeriodTypeName = i.ListPeriods.Select(lp => lp.PeriodType.PeriodTypeName)
                }).ToList()
```

---

My model section like this :
[image]

but i  get the following exception :

> The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property
>   defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation
>   properties and the Select operator for collection navigation
>   properties. Parameter name: path

**The result should be the datasource to Gridview.**

Comment: check this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: you cannot include a object. you actually have to include the Navigation Property. If you want to include two properties, do it with Include().Include().

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You cannot use *Include* to select data like this. *Include* is used to load related data. You should load your entities using *Include* then select what you want. Remember to remove *.ToString()* from *CompanyId*. EF will do it for you. Your query should look like this:

```
var incomeList = ctx.IncomeLists
    .Include(i => i.Company)
    .Include(i => i.ListPeriods.Select(lp => lp.PeriodType))
    .Select(i => new 
    {
        CompanyTitle =  i.CompanyId + "/" + i.Company.CompanyName,
        PeriodTypeNames = i.ListPeriods.Select(lp => lp.PeriodType.PeriodTypeName)
    })
    .ToList();
```