# The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type.

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, eager-loading

My linq query

```
   model.Questions = db.Questions
                     .Where (x => x.CategoriesID == categoryId)
                     .Include (qc => qc.QuestionCounters.Where(x => x.MemberID == User.Identity.GetUserId()))
                     .Include (qf => qf.QuestionFavorites.Where(x => x.MemberId == User.Identity.GetUserId()))
                     .Include (qt => qt.QuestionTags)
                     .ToList();
```

produces the error

> 'The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property
>   defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation
>   properties and the Select operator for collection navigation
>   properties.'

Any ideas why is this happening?

Comment: You can't use Include to select data. There are lots of posts on this already.

Comment: @Equalsk Are there any alternatives? This one freaks me out

Comment: Duplicate - See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15980665/ef-lambda-the-include-path-expression-must-refer-to-a-navigation-property and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38676029/the-include-path-expression-must-refer-to-a-navigation-property-defined-on-the-t.

Comment: You can't have "Where" in your include expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Ended up with

```
 IQueryable<HomeViewModel> test = db.Questions
                                  .Where(x => x.CategoriesID == categoryId)
                                  .Select(q => q.ToHomeViewModel(User.Identity.GetUserId()));
```

and

```
public static HomeViewModel ToHomeViewModel(this Question q, string memberId)
{
    return new HomeViewModel()
    {
        QuestionCounters = q.QuestionCounters.Where(x => x.MemberID == memberId),
        QuestionFavorites = q.QuestionFavorites.Where(x => x.MemberId == memberId),
        QuestionTags = q.QuestionTags
    };
}
```

How needs `include` after all? ;)

Thanks for commenting @jle

Answer (score 2):

As some people commented, you cannot use `Where` method in Include.

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Plus](http://entityframework-plus.net/)

EF+ Query IncludeFilter feature allow filtering related entities.

```
model.Questions = db.Questions
                 .Where (x => x.CategoriesID == categoryId)
                 .IncludeFiler (qc => qc.QuestionCounters.Where(x => x.MemberID == User.Identity.GetUserId()))
                 .IncludeFiler (qf => qf.QuestionFavorites.Where(x => x.MemberId == User.Identity.GetUserId()))
                 .IncludeFiler (qt => qt.QuestionTags)
                 .ToList();
```

Wiki: [EF+ Query IncludeFilter](http://entityframework-plus.net/query-include-filter)

**Solution #2**

Another technique is by using projection (which is what my library do under the hood)

```
bd.Questions
     .Select(q = new {
        Question = q,
        QuestionCounters = q.QuestionCounters.Where(x => x.MemberID == memberId),
        QuestionFavorites = q.QuestionFavorites.Where(x => x.MemberId == memberId),
        QuestionTags = q.QuestionTags
     })
     .ToList()
     .Select(x => x.Question)
     .ToList();
```