# Linq query with where clause on related data

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I have a data context using two SQL tables ( A and B) that are queried using the following code:

```
                    var query = from b in _ctx.A
                                .Where(b => b.Flag == true).Include(c => c.B)
                                select b;
```

The Flag column resides in the table A. I want to add an additional where clause to the query that checks for a column named Qty in table B for values > 10.

I tried the following code but got an error:

```
                    var query = from b in _ctx.A
                                .Where(b => b.Flag == true)
                                .Include(c => c.B.Where(i => i.Qty >= 10))
                                select b;
```

Error:
The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties. Parameter name: path

I found this reference:
[The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type.in eager loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38676029/the-include-path-expression-must-refer-to-a-navigation-property-defined-on-the-t)

but I don't understand how to use the select for my query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The include Path is just there to load a property, if it is not loaded for any other reason.

The navigation collection cannot be filtered, since it's establishing the relation. It has always the meaning of "all associated entities somewhere else".

But we can reverse the query, assuming classB has a Property A of classA.

```
             var query = _ctx.B
                            .Where(b => b.Qty >=10 && b.A.Flag);
                            .Include(b => b.A)
```

The Where clause in this case will not load the property B, this is just evaluated on the server. The include here is really necessary to fill the property A.

Now you get a list of all B's with associated A.
If you want your collection of A's, you can group By A

```
             var query = _ctx.B
                            .Where(b => b.Qty >=10 && b.A.Flag)
                            .GroupBy(x => x.A);
```

This will result in a collection of A, with all associated B's that have Qty>10.

Comment: I'm getting errors on all 3 suggested answers: The second suggestion gives me the error: Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type bool and IEnumerable

Comment: Not sure if this is important but my context is defined as follows: public virtual DbSet<classA> A {get;set;}    and  public virtual DbSet<classB> B{get;set;}. The query does not expose the DbSet B.

Comment: I do not see your class, but your include let me assume, your class A has a Property named B, probably stored in DbSet B ? That doesn't matter. You do have a relation established from A to B, with a foreign key, etc.? Do you ? 
How can b, be a DBSet ?
On `_ctx.A.Where(b =>`, b is a variable of type class A. Definitly. That's what it says. There is no point in my suggesstion using or requesting a DbSet<B>.

Comment: My classA and classB are linked with an ID. The classB contains the column I want to filter on.

Comment: Right, you were misleading me, is it a 1:N relation ? 1 A multiple B, probably yes.
What do you want to load ? All the B's with associated A ? That would be easier. 
The Navigation collection cannot be filtered when loading. It's by definition of the relation. It has to be always "All the B's that A has.".
We can reverse it, does the class B also has a property A ?

Comment: Edited the answer, hope that's better.