# The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, entity-framework, linq

**Error->** The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties.\r\nParameter name: path

**Result wanted ->** get the category by given id and list of top 5 books related to that id which are active in Books table

**Code ->**

```cs
return dbContext.Categories
   .Include(x => x.Books.Where(book => book.is_active == true).ToList().Take(5))
   .Where(x => x.id == Id && x.is_active == true)
   .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Have you seen this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38676029/the-include-path-expression-must-refer-to-a-navigation-property-defined-on-the-t? seems like you are using the include in a way it is not meant to be, you should include the data first and then select it

Comment: get rid of `.ToList()`

Comment: IMHO flip the query to `dbContext.Books.Where(...).Include(b => b.Category).Take(5)`